# How to improve aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I have pipeline

```
   [
       {'$match':{templateId:ObjectId('blabla')}},
       {
               "$sort" : {
                   "_id" : 1
               }
           },
           {
               "$facet" : {
                   "paginatedResult" : [
                       {
                           "$skip" : 0
                       },
                       {
                           "$limit" : 100
                       }
                   ],
                   "totalCount" : [
                       {
                           "$count" : "count"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           }
       
       ])
```

Index:

```
    "key" : {
        "templateId" : 1,
        "_id" : 1
    }
```

Collection has 10.6M documents 500k of it is with needed templateId.
Aggregate use index

```
"planSummary" : "IXSCAN { templateId: 1, _id: 1 }",
```

But the request takes 16 seconds. What i did wrong? How to speed up it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start, you should get rid of the `$sort` operator. The documents are already sorted by _id since the documents are already guaranteed to sorted by the `{ templateId: 1, _id: 1 }` index. The outcome is sorting 500k which are already sorted anyway.

Next, you shouldn't use the `$skip` approach. For high page numbers you will skip large numbers of documents up to almost 500k (rather index entries, but still).

I suggest an alternative approach:

For the first page, calculate an id you know for sure falls out of the left side of the index. Say, if you know that you don't have entries back dated to 2019 and before, you can use a match operator similar to this:

```
var pageStart = ObjectId.fromDate(new Date("2020/01/01"))
```

Then, your match operator should look like this:

```
{'$match' : {templateId:ObjectId('blabla'), _id: {$gt: pageStart}}}
```

For the next pages, keep track of the last document of the previous page: if the rightmost document `_id` is `x` in a certain page, then `pageStart` should be `x` for the next page.

So your pipeline may look like this:

```
[        
   {'$match' : {templateId:ObjectId('blabla'), _id: {$gt: pageStart}}},
   {
       "$facet" : {
           "paginatedResult" : [
               {
                   "$limit" : 100
               }
           ]
        
       }
   }
]
```

Note, that now the `$skip` is missing from the `$facet` operator as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, i knowm than i shouldnt use skip, but my front need paginator... So... I need to $skip and $count in one aggregate

Comment: Well in that case, I would suggest implementing a custom pagination mechanism by keeping a track of last read document per client as outlined above. You can count and cache the number of document in a separate query. It won't be accurate, I know. But something should compromised, performance, possible stale data, extra lines of code if not using the driver pagination abstraction. You had said it yourself. You can't have it: 15 seconds for a single invocation. The redundant `$sort` may save a bit, but `$count` for every call is a bone in your throat